# How to pass value of function to another?

Tags: javascript, function

I am making a program of Taylor and MacLaurin Series wherein it'll show the graphical representation of it in DESMOS API.

It only shows the graph of `f(x) = sin(x)`, however the additional equation doesn't show. I couldn't pass the equation in the `graphSinX();`
In my graph.js file, I have this function:

```
function  graphSinX(){
 var seqn = document.getElementById("numberOfSequence").value;
 var equation = '';
  for (var z = 0; z <= seqn; z++) {
    equation += `(((-1)^${z}*(x^{2*${z}+1})))/ (2*${z}+ 1)! +`;
        if (z == this.n) {
      equation = equation.slice(0, -1);
      return equation;
    }
  }
}

var sinEquation = graphSinX();

var elt1 = document.getElementById('calculatorSinX');
var calculatorSinX = Desmos.GraphingCalculator(elt1);
calculatorSinX.setExpression({id:'graph1', latex:'f(x)=\\sin x'});
calculatorSinX.setExpression({id:'graph2', latex: sinEquation });
```

Comment: What is `this.n` supposed to be?

Comment: You should _always_ convert the input value to an integer - `z <= +seqn`

Comment: this.n should be seqn

Comment: "this.n should be seqn" edit perhaps?